# Documentation for Javascript code in RStudio?

Tags: rstudio, jsdoc3

RStudio has support for ROxygen for generating documentation for R code.  My R package has a fair bit of Javascript code in it.  Has anyone written an RStudio plugin to support Javascript documentation, using JSDoc for example?

I'd like the equivalent of "Insert ROxygen skeleton", which isn't trivial to write myself, since it needs to parse the following Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's now a prototype addin for RStudio to do this.  It currently uses the development version of the `js` package, so you'll need two Github installs to use it:

```
devtools::install_github("jeroen/js")
devtools::install_github("dmurdoch/JSDocPlugin")
```

See the `?insertJSDocAddin` help topic for instructions on how to install it with a keyboard shortcut.

Comments or pull requests on https://github.com/dmurdoch/JSDocPlugin would be welcome.